# Ansible returns only one item from a dictionary

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get a list of IPs from an specific Service, and ansible returns only one item from the loop.
I have tried many things and is always the same result.
Need help.

```
- name: "Amazon IPs"
  include_vars:
    file: /home/user1/ansible/AWS/ip-ranges.json
    name: amazon


# - set_fact:
# #       # test: "{{ (variable.stdout | from_json).prefixes | map(attribute='ip_prefix') | list }}"
#     amazonipv4: "{{ item }}"
# #       amazonipv6: "{{ amazon.ipv6_prefixes | map(attribute='ipv6_prefix') | list }}"
#   loop: "{{amazon.prefixes | map(attribute='ip_prefix') | list }}"
#   # when: '"AMAZON" in item.service'


- set_fact:
    test3: "{{item.ip_prefix}}"
  loop: "{{amazon.prefixes | list }}"
  when: '"AMAZON" in item.service'
- debug:
    var: test3
```

I expect to get a list based on the service, but I only get one item.

example:

`TASK [debug] ***********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "test3": "54.190.198.32/28"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in each iteration in the `set_fact` loop, you are setting the value, not pushing to a list. you need to change your syntax to:

```
- set_fact:
  test3: "{{ test3 | default([]) + [item.ip_prefix] }}"
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Amazing.
Thank you very much for your help and time!